# beautifulsoup to extract text in between two tags

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have this HTML snippet:

```
<h3>Language</h3>
    <a class="syllabus-item" href="">French</a>
    <a class="syllabus-item" href="">English</a>
    <a class="syllabus-item" href="">Spanish</a>

<h3>Music</h3>
    <a class="syllabus-item" href="">Rock</a>
    <a class="syllabus-item" href="">Pop</a>
```

And I want the output to be:

```
1 - Language/1 - French
1 - Language/2 - English
1 - Language/3 - Spanish
2 - Music/1 - Rock
2 - Music/2 -Pop
```

And here's my code

```
def get_genre_band(soup):
    genre = None
    for node in soup.findAll(['h3', 'a']):
        if node.name == 'h3':
            genre = node.text
        elif 'syllabus-item' in node.get('class', ''):
            yield genre.strip(), node.text.strip()
```

and I'm using it like this:

```
            for g, b in get_genre_band(section):
            print("{} \n\t{}".format(g, b))
```

But I cannot get the proper numeration, I get something like this:

```
1 - Language/1 - French
1 - Language/2 - English
1 - Language/3 - Spanish
8 - Music/4 - Rock
9 - Music/5 -Pop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`.next_sibling`**](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling) for this task.

**Code:**

```
for i, header in enumerate(soup.find_all('h3'), 1):
    next_tag = header
    j = 1
    while True:
        next_tag = next_tag.next_sibling
        if next_tag is None or next_tag.name == 'h3':
            break
        if next_tag.name is not None:
            print('{} - {}/{} - {}'.format(i, header.text, j, next_tag.string))
            j += 1
```

**Output:**

```
1 - Language/1 - French
1 - Language/2 - English
1 - Language/3 - Spanish
2 - Music/1 - Rock
2 - Music/2 - Pop
```